# Print out a HTML document in C#

Tags: c#, html, .net

I have a program in c#(.net). The program has a simple function and is suppose to write out the result in a HTML document. I have a HTML code inside the program (all code is inside console.writeline).
It works when I run it in the command window. But the project is to print out the result in a HTML file.

I was given an example of a command line:

```
*Nameofproject*.exe 5 > Result.html
```

Can anyone help me figuring this out?

Comment: What happens when you run the command line as given?

Comment: Just do that, run your .exe file and add "> nameoffile.html" at the end to redirect console output to a file...

Comment: Put nameofproheect.exe > name.html inside my program. And add "> nameoffile.html" to my exe file?

Answer (score 0):

here's how to do it with a text file: [How to save Console.WriteLine output to text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470700/how-to-save-console-writeline-output-to-text-file) 
and here [C# How to save Console.Writeline Outputs to HTML Format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478595/c-sharp-how-to-save-console-writeline-outputs-to-html-format)
html should be the same thing.